# How do I use md5 instead of bcrypt?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I need to use `md5()` instead of `bcrypt()` for storing passwords. But when I just do this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return Account::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => md5($data['password']),
        'datetoday' => Carbon::now(),
        'lastip' => request()->ip(),
        'confirmation' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

When I try to login it says the credentials are wrong.

Comment: Although using MD5 to hash passwords is a horrible, terrible idea, you need to use the same method both to decrypt and encrypt the password (you still have bcrypt in the confirmation).

Comment: Why do you need to? md5() is less secure.

Comment: Because the db is connected to a game of which I don't have the control and it checks the passwords on md5

Comment: For what reason is the downvote? I don't have a choice but to use md5 to make it work.

Comment: A much more secure way would be to use bcrypt for your own login, and when the user logs in save an MD5 hash of the password temporarily in memory. That way you can still use the MD5 when needed but store the passwords securely.

Comment: @SinanSamet Is this really worth compronising the user's security?

Comment: It's a private server game with few people the security is not that much of an issue

Comment: In case you are using md5 because you are migrating existing users you can do something like this : https://medium.com/@ed.sav/laravel-migrating-existing-site-users-with-md5-passwords-b7e2a14eded4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Using md5() over bcrypt() is not recommended.**

However you can manually authenticate user. Override [`login()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L28) method in LoginController

```
  public function login(Request $request)
  {
     $user = User::where('username', $request->username)
                  ->where('password',md5($request->password))
                  ->first();
     Auth::login($user);
     return redirect('/');
  }
```

Comment: @SinanSamet override `login()` instead.

Comment: Yes, it will work, yes it will compromise user security. Is it a good idea to help?

Comment: It tells me `Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth' not found` while I did `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;`

Comment: @SanzeebAryal well that obviously wouldn't help if she is to create users via API for those little users. It is sad how everyone is dodging the question and telling her it is not safe. It is not safe alright but does it mean there is no way to do it? like forcing laravel to use md5()?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create new service provider.

app/providers/md5hashprovier.php

```
namespace App\Providers;
class MD5HashProvider extends \Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
    \App::bind('hash', function () {
        return new \App\Classes\MD5Hasher;
    });
}}
```

Next you have to create the MD5Hasher class. I'd suggest to locate it to 
app/classes/MD5Hasher.php

```
class MD5Hasher extends BcryptHasher
{
public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array())
   {
      $user = User::wherePassword(md5($value))->first();
      return $user ? true : false
    }
}
```

and register your new service provider to config/app.php in providers array

```
\App\Providers\MD5HashProvider::class,
```

This would enable auth with md5 password

Comment: I tried this too but it still doesn't login. It says wrong credentials

Comment: i've taken this from project. try to die('asd') - did asd appeared? if not - you missed something

Comment: For anyone wondering why the MD5Hasher class doesn't work, you need to include these:
namespace App\Classes;
use Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher as BcryptHasher;
use App\User as user;

Comment: What would happen if several users used the same password? Only the hashed password is searched for, is there any relation to the username/e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

Using MD5 is not a good idea anymore.

To get rid of the old MD5 records you can use the second trick here: http://john.cuppi.net/migrate-from-md5-to-bcrypt-password-hashes/