# How to modify default bcrypt hashing into md5 in laravel 5.4

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, hash, bcrypt, laravel-5.4

I have a password in MD5, and I want to import user in Laravel 5.4 because Laravel don't allow to log in using imported user based on md5 due to bcrypt hashing.

```
1) Is there any way to use MD5 instead of bcrypt?
2) How can I use the original password to store in Laravel with default bcrypt?
```

The main purpose of doing this is to use md5 encrypted password in Laravel after importing users in Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Duplicate question this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176866/how-do-i-use-md5-instead-of-bcrypt

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like most hash functions, MD5 is neither encryption nor encoding. It can be cracked by brute-force attack and suffers from extensive vulnerabilities as detailed in the security section below.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

I wouldn't change the password hashing to MD5, instead I would create a page where users can update their password.

Simply create a page with 4 input fields:

- email
- old password
- new password
- verify new password.

If the old MD5 password matches, update their password using `bcrypt()` and they can login to your Laravel application. You can add info & link to the login page and send an email to all your users with the info and link.

Comment: It is not that MD5 is "broken", it is that just using a hash function is not sufficient. See the comment to the question for more details.