# Laravel 5.5 how to modify login process to use existant db User Table (SQL Server)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I am a begginer in Laravel. Sorry for any stupid question.
My scenario it the following:
There is a previous db in Sql Server with a user table. This table is called USUARIO_EMITENTE. This table has a key field called 'user' and a 'password' field that uses md5 (is not my fault, it was already there).
So, I changed the User model in order to use this table like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $table = 'Usuario_Emitente';
}
```

my loginController is the default one (using laravel 5.5):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Now, I have to change the LoginController to:
1) Get the Field 'user' instead of default email of laravel Auth ;
2) use md5 instead of bcrypt;
3) Once logged redirect to /menu

Do I have to change any other class to do it?

Does anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This login process requires a few things — setting the form data names, setting up a Route for the login form, and mapping the route to logic that does the hashing and redirection/validation checks. (You could add server validation and an error message, too).

(1) when you submit the form for Auth you'd use names user and say pass,

(2) in routes.php you route your POST auth URL to LoginController (new method) loginUser:

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@loginUser');
```

(3) Add logic to your loginUser() function handling the crypt, field data, and redirection (You’d also theoretically want to run validation and checks on the inputs here). NOTE: According to a the community, md5 over bcrypt is NOT recommended, but it can be done manually ([How do I use md5 instead of bcrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176866/how-do-i-use-md5-instead-of-bcrypt))!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function loginUser()
    {
        // $data = \Request::all();
        $user = \Request::input(‘user’);
        $pass = \Request::input(‘pass’);

        if ( !isset($user) || !isset($pass) ) {
            // Bad Creds. No access!
            return redirect('/loginPage');
        } else {

            $user = User::where('user', $user)->where('password', md5($pass))->first();

            if ($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect()->intended('/');
            } else {/* No User Found? */}

        }
    }

}
```

(4) According to the same post above, you also have to create a new Service Provider for MD5 for use in your LoginController Class. This allows you the user of “md5(…)” as above. Because another user answered that question, though, I’ll leave the link for you to follow to see what he did.

Hope this helps.

**Reference**

[md5 over bcrypt in Laravel5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176866/how-do-i-use-md5-instead-of-bcrypt)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tell me something what do you think about to override login() method in LoginController to do almost the same? it is good?

Comment: So long as you also update your route to map to that login method, definitely -- the code would be then be functionally equivalent.